# In Python, how could we write sql query that only pulls specific columns available in list?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Currently, I am pulling the data from SQL Server in Python with this query below:

```
df = db.query("SELECT * FROM rpt_SalesHistoryMAST where GLPostDate>'2017-08-31' order by GLPostDate;")
```

This table consists of more than 500 columns. I have a list of 100 columns that I want to pull.

How could I write a sql query in Python that only pull those specific columns in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to build a comma-separated string of the delimited column names and then format that into your SQL statement:

```
>>> column_names = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]  # sample data
>>> column_string = ",".join(f"[{x}]" for x in column_names)
>>> column_string
'[first_name],[last_name],[email]'
>>> sql = f"SELECT {column_string} FROM [tablename] WHERE ..."
>>> sql
'SELECT [first_name],[last_name],[email] FROM [tablename] WHERE ...'
```

... or, to be even more robust in case a column name might contain a right square bracket:

```
>>> column_names = ["start time", "duration [minutes]"]
>>> column_string = ",".join(f"[{x.replace(']',']]')}]" for x in column_names)
>>> column_string
'[start time],[duration [minutes]]]'
```